# Unable to restart network manager or run sudo commands after suspend

Tags: network-manager, suspend, gnome-terminal

After waking my computer from suspend networking is disabled and won't turn on. If I try to run "sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service" or similar in the terminal the command will never complete, I just get stuck with a terminal that i cant run any more commands in. And no other sudo commands will complete, just stuck after hitting enter.

[image: Terminal after entering a command]

```
andrew@andrew-Flex-3-1570:~$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-10-23 12:46:55 PDT; 27min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
  Process: 31992 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31992 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─5381 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           └─6144 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkMa

Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 23 12:46:55 andrew-Flex-3-1570 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

The only way i have been able to resolve this is to restart (sometimes forced) my computer.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo Flex 3-1570.

Comment: Please avoid upload terminal screenshot, instead copy the output to the post.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it is not in suspended state. It happens randomly even when the system is not in suspend state. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

my system was in a state that appears to be similar to that described here just now.  systemctl restart hangs the terminal window, sudo hangs the terminal window -- and ^C ^Z ^\ etc does not work.

i had an external usb-ethernet dongle plugged into the system via a usb hub.

after power-cycling the usb hub it was in -- and restarting the computer without ethernet -- everything started working fine.  plugged the ethernet dongle back in and ethernet is working again.

of course, this is not repeatable since i have no idea how to put the dongle hardware in a confused state -- maybe static discharge? -- so it's hard to confirm anything.  i'm just putting this here so that there's a record, and if somebody encounters something similar they can try it (and upvote).